# Cannot Find Column in Row

Tags: php, mysql

Folks, I'm writing this piece of SQL for my application:

```
SELECT concat(c.contact_first_name,' ',c.contact_last_name) as user,
sum(tl.task_log_hours) as total_hours,
sum(tl1.task_log_hours) as billable_hours
FROM u364432559_dotpd.dotp_task_log tl, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_contacts c, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_projects p, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_companies co, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_tasks tk, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_users u
LEFT JOIN u364432559_dotpd.dotp_task_log tl1 on tl.task_log_creator = tl1.task_log_creator ... //where clauses omitted for brevity//
```

And when I run it it says "`Unknown column 'tl.task_log_creator' in 'on clause'`". Why is that? The tl table is referenced before that and I'm joining tl1.

This query is to fetch the name of the user, sum of hours (total hours) and sum of billable hours (there's a special flag on the table that tells that). I'm also open to suggestions if this is the best way to achieve the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a lot of tables in form you must use `()` for all them to be seen in JOIN. So:

```
FROM (u364432559_dotpd.dotp_task_log tl, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_contacts c, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_projects p, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_companies co, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_tasks tk, u364432559_dotpd.dotp_users u)
```